# Each Click I want to increase the font size using jquery

Tags: jquery

For each click I want to increase the font size.

```
$('#fontplus').each(function('click') {
    var fs = $('#bod').css('font-size');
    $('#bod').css('font-size',fs+1);

});

<div id="fontplus">+</div>
```

Thanks
Jean

Comment: you should tell if you have some errors or what is happening wrong. people may not want to help you if you don't provide minimum informations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as you have probably discovered, that won't work.

```
$('#fontplus').click(function() {
  var fs = $('#bod').css('fontSize');
```

Now you have the current font size. However, what is it?  Is it "12px"? Or perhaps it's "1.5em"?  Well, assuming you control that, what you'll need to do is take apart the current setting and then put together the new value:

```
  $('#bod').css('fontSize', (parseInt(fs, 10) + 1) + 'px');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually want them to be able to do this infinitely? I would suggest having 3 or 4  different CSS classes to represent each available font size and manage it with jQuery.

The other examples don't even consider the units used! Points? Pixels? .css("font-size") will return that, so doing a ++ won't work.

```
$("#fontplus").click(function() {
    switch($("#bod").attr("className"))
    {
        case "large" : /* do nothing */ break;
        case "medium" : $("#bod").removeClass("medium").addClass("large"); break;
        /* do as needed */
    }
});
```

and I would have each css class look like:

```
.large { font-size: 1.4em; }
.medium { font-size: 1.2em; }
.normal { font-size: 1em; }
.small { font-size: .8em; }
```

Comment: Better yet, keep the classes in a little object so that instead of a switch statement you just look up the current class and use the value stored as the next class. Like, `var steps = {"small": "medium", "medium": "large", "large": "largest", "largest": "largest"};` and then the handler is just `$('#bod').attr('className', steps[$('#bod').attr('className')]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
   var bod;
   var fontPlus;
   $(document).ready(function() {
      bod = $('#bod');
      fontPlus = $('#fontPlus');
      fontPlus.click(function() {
         var fontSize = bod.css('font-size');
         var fontSizeNum = parseFloat(fontSize, 10);
         bod.css('font-size', fontSizeNum * 1.2);
      });
   });
```

more info and examples [here](http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/text-resizing-with-jquery/)

Comment: :) did not accuse you downvoting my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the click event:

```
$('#fontplus').click(function() {
    var fs = $('#bod').css('font-size');
    $('#bod').css('font-size',fs+1);
});
```

You will need to set the initial font-size in CSS to an integer value.